# ARM Interrupt Handling in QEMU

Tags: arm, qemu, interrupt-handling

I'm trying to understand how QEMU handles interrupts for ARM processors. I have a bare metal  binary blob (ie, not linux -- just some assembly code) which was built for a ARM1176. When run in QEMU, during initialisation the code in the binary blob sets bit 13 of the CPSR indicating that the interrupt vector table is located at `0xFFFF0000`. Hooking up GDB and dumping the instructions at that address, I can indeed see the corresponding interrupt vector table. On an IRQ, it jumps to `0xFFFF0018`, which just does a jump to `0xFFFF00070`, which has the code for the first irq_handler, and ultimately jumps to a second irq_handler.

That's fine, but when I look at hooking up interrupts in QEMU every reference I find is hooking up my own irq_handler. If you allocate an irq, I need to provide a `qemu_irq_handler` that gets called when the IRQ is fired. But in this case, I don't want my own handler to get called. I was assuming that QEMU would emulate the ARM processor and jump to `0xFFFF0018` when I, for instance, called `qemu_set_irq()` and start running the code there.

I'm sure something is lacking in my understanding, but is there not some way to get QEMU to jump to the interrupt vector table and run the code there when triggering an interrupt, for example, with `qemu_set_irq()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that QEMU is using [Paravirtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paravirtualization) for the ARM.  There is no **interrupt controller** for the ARM device on a PC.  I think the `qemu_irq_handler` is a **paravirtualization** technique to handle an interrupt.  Where are **interrupts** going to come from?  See: [QEMU tech document](https://qemu.weilnetz.de/w64/2012/2012-08-24/qemu-tech.html#Hardware-interrupts) especially,

> 2.11 Hardware interrupts
>
> In order to be faster, QEMU does not check at every basic block if a hardware interrupt is pending. Instead, the user must asynchronously call a specific function to tell that an interrupt is pending. This function resets the chaining of the currently executing basic block. It ensures that the execution will return soon in the main loop of the CPU emulator. Then the main loop can test if the interrupt is pending and handle it.

Probably QEMU comes with some code to emulate devices.  However, if you want to use your own device, you will need to do something custom.  It is not an *actual* ARM processor.  Most **virtualization** technology [have issues](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dto0013b/DTO0013B_tzic_sp890_r0p0_to.pdf) with interrupts; even when the virtualization is hosted by the same CPU as the target.

Comment: Actually, it seems that calling `cpu_interrupt(&env, CPU_INTERRUPT_HARD);` is what I was looking that. That jumps to the interrupt vector table and continues executing from there.

Comment: This works if you can update your code, where you want an interrupt to happen.  My answer was written to think about cases where you don't/can't update the code.  So, both are probably valuable.